# Return a generated ID as a variable upon adding an entry through a php function to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, null

I've created a function in php to add some information to a table. However the ID gets created upon entry. But I need that Id in order to perform another task, but I'm not actually sure how to get that entry.

SO my function is this:

```
addSkillset($agent, $computing, $tactical, $driving);
```

Which does this:

```
function addProperty($agent, $computing, $tactical, $driving) {
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    if (!$mysqli) {
            die('There was a problem connecting to the database.');
    }
    else {
    $query = "INSERT INTO Skillset VALUES (NULL, '$agent', '$computing', '$tactical', '$driving')";
    }
    if ($Results = mysql_query($query)){
    echo "added";
    }
    $mysqli->close();
}
```

So in this query, the 'NULL' bit is what I'm trying to identify and return.

I assume I would have to put:

```
if ($Results = mysql_query($query)){
    $somesortofvariable = somesortofcommand;
    return $somesortofvariable;
}
```

But I'm not totally sure.

Comment: [**Bazinga!**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [mysqli_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.insert-id.php)

```
if ($Results = mysqli_query($query)){
    $somesortofvariable = mysqli_insert_id();
    return $somesortofvariable;
}
```

Comment: If I'm honest I wanted to do that to create a prepared statement...but I don't know how to do it with insert statements (only got it working for select statements). I tried it and it banjaxed on me unfortunately. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should look into using [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php):

```
if($Results = mysqli_query($query))
{
    return mysqli_insert_id();
}
```

Please note, though, the large red box at the top of the API Reference docs:

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in
>   the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.
>   See also [MySQL: choosing an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) guide and [related FAQ](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more
>   information. Alternatives to this function include:
>
> - [`mysqli_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)
> - [`PDO::lastInsertId()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

I did note that you're using MySQLi, but you're running a standard `mysql_query()`. Maybe that's a typo on your code, but I thought that I'd mention it in case...